# React application / .NET API IIS site deployment to multiple sites / different URLs, best approach?

Tags: reactjs, iis, devops, publish

Probably a dumb question but doing infra/DevOps work and need to deploy a react application with .NET api (two sites) to 10 different IIS sites with different URLs. With the API URL and API (diff DB strings) having differences for each site, what is the best approach for separating them out for deployment? Separate code branches for each with the set variables and deploy that. Due to infra limitations, I cannot deploy to production with CI/CD, so I will have to manually deploy 10 "different" code bases, which sounds like a nightmare but unsure how else to approach it.

I tried to add environments for each in React but did not account for the API changes, which makes the different branch approaches make more sense.

Comment: Although multiple IIS sites can bind to the same physical path. The API URL and API (diff DB strings) having differences for each site. It might be better to put the application files in different IIS folders. Environment variables can also be set in each site's respective web.config file in IIS. By separation you mean binding different pages to different sites/URLs?